# Django update view won't save

Tags: python, django

I have this update view but it will not save upon form submission. 5 minutes ago everything was working fine and then I added the edit feature for user posts and all of a sudden nothing will save when trying to edit things.

users app views:

```
class UserEditProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    model = UserProfile
    fields = [
            'first_name',
            'profile_pic',
            'location',
            'title',
            'user_type',
            'website',
            'about',
            'twitter',
            'dribbble',
            'github'
            ]
    template_name_suffix = '_edit_form'

    def get_success_url(self):
        userid = self.kwargs['pk']
        return reverse_lazy('users:user_profile',kwargs={'pk': userid})
```

users app models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='User')
    join_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',null=True,blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    user_type = models.IntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES,default=1)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=500,default='about')
    twitter = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    dribbble = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    github = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.userprofile.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

user profile_edit_form.html:

```
{% extends "users/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="form-title">
        <h2 class="form-title-text">Edit Profile</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="user-forms-base">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

I am having the same issue with updating posts on the home page, however I am assuming the issues are the same and so I'll be able to just replicate this solution over there.

Comment: You could try and override methods such as `form_invalid` to print and debug what is sent across, to see what (likely) invalidates the form and thus saving of the data.

Comment: Can you run it with Debug = False in settings.py and provide a traceback..

Comment: It is advisable not to define Django Signals inside models modules or application modules, put them outside i.e. the `@receiver` be  defined outside the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone mentioned this in the comments but basically the form was returning in valid so I override `form_invalid` to print any errors that may have been causing it. This showed that it was sending a `string` when it was expecting an `int` at the model level. Once I switched it back to send an `int` the problem went away and now it works. Thanks guys.